# JAX-RS client: ResponseProcessingException handling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-7

Some overloaded call request methods, such as: `get()` and `post(Entity<?> entity)` (there are others) of [`SyncInvoker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html) return a `Response` object, rather than the unmarshalled content.

I noticed that in the case of [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#get--), there is no documented [`ResponseProcessingException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ResponseProcessingException.html), while other methods, such as all 3 overloaded   [`post`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post-javax.ws.rs.client.Entity-) methods, may throw a `ResponseProcessingException`.

I'm aware that `ResponseProcessingException` is a `RuntimeException` which inherits from [`ProcessingException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ProcessingException.html), but I still would interpret this to mean that the `get()` method won't throw a `ResponseProcessingException`.

**Is this correct? What about [`ClientResponseFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientResponseFilter.html)? Why is the behavior different than the behavior of the other call request methods (`put`, `post`,..)?**

Also, the Javadoc for the methods which do throw a `ResponseProcessingException` says:

> in case processing of a received HTTP response fails (e.g. in a filter
>   or during conversion of the response entity data to an instance of a
>   particular Java type).

The part:

> or during conversion of the response entity data to an instance of a
>   particular Java type

seems to be wrong here, as the `readEntity` method should not yet have been called:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9915

**Is this a copy & paste documentation error?**

I guess a filter would be a valid case, though.

Comment: @BalcusC This is a Java question, JAX-RS is part of Java EE and JAX-RS Clients is a part of JAVA EE 7. Please see the links to the Javadoc. Please don't remove these tags.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is certainly inconsistent. It's clear that `ResponseProcessingException` is intended to be thrown when a `ClientResponseFilter` fails.

The implementation I'm looking at (RESTEasy 3.0.16) does this:

```
try {
    filter.filter(requestContext, responseContext);
} catch (ResponseProcessingException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Throwable e) {
    throw new ResponseProcessingException(response, e);
}
```

There is no reason that the `get` method would not declare the exception when the `put` and `post` methods do. Internally they are all handled by the same code.

My conclusion is that the slight difference in documentation between the methods is just an oversight.

Interestingly, in my copy of the source code, the `get()` method has this line in its javadoc:

```
/**
 * @throws javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException
 *          in case the invocation processing has failed.
```

While all the other similar methods (e.g. `get(Class<T>)`) are documented like this:

```
/**
 * @throws ProcessingException         in case the request processing or subsequent I/O operation fails.
```

What catches my eye is the fully qualified class name in the first one. Just a hunch, but that makes me think it was put in at a different time or by a different person. Maybe I'm overanalysing. I tried to look at the revision history, but all I found was a single commit saying "move source code to its own repository"). So much for that.

However, as you pointed out, it's not an error, since `ResponseProcessingException` is and a subclass of `ProcessingException` and isn't even a checked exception anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your exception wrapped in `ResponseProcessingException`, you can make your exception extend it, then it will come without wrapping. Of course, this is feasible only if you use your own exception and you are OK with RuntimeException.